# C++ QtSoap doesn't work: "undefined reference to `QtSoapHttpTransport::QtSoapHttpTransport(QObject*)`

Tags: c++, qt, soap, qt-creator

i am trying to get QtSoap working. I am using this library: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-solutions/yjyong1217s-qt-solutions/source/4d83ff38ad836e507730034293d092df40b6d034:qtsoap

This is my Code

```
#include "sevSOAP.h"

sevSOAP::sevSOAP(int number1, int number2, QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), http(this)
{
    this->number1 = number1;
    this->number2 = number2;

    http.setHost(host);
    // Or use just http.setHost(host)
    connect(&http, SIGNAL(responseReady()), this, SLOT(getResponse()));

}

void sevSOAP::sum()
{
    QtSoapMessage request;

    request.setMethod("sum");
    request.addMethodArgument("number1", "", number1);
    request.addMethodArgument("number2", "", number2);

    http.submitRequest(request, "/soma");
}

void sevSOAP::getResponse()
{
    const QtSoapMessage &message = http.getResponse();
    if (message.isFault()) {
        qDebug("Error: %s", qPrintable(message.faultString().toString()));
    }
    qDebug()<< message.returnValue().toString();
}
```

And this is the header file:

```
#ifndef SEVSOAP_H
#define SEVSOAP_H

#include <qtsoap.h>

class sevSOAP : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        int number1;
        int number2;

        sevSOAP(int number1, int number2, QObject *parent = 0);
        void sum();

    private slots:
        void getResponse();

    private:
        QtSoapHttpTransport http;
};

#endif
```

No matter what i am doing, it always throws out these compiling errors:

```
C:\Projects/sevSOAP.cpp:3: undefined reference to `QtSoapHttpTransport::QtSoapHttpTransport(QObject*)'
C:\Projects/sevSOAP.cpp:8: undefined reference to `QtSoapHttpTransport::setHost(QString const&, bool, int)'
C:\Projects/sevSOAP.cpp:12: undefined reference to `QtSoapHttpTransport::~QtSoapHttpTransport()'
C:\Projects/sevSOAP.cpp:3: undefined reference to `QtSoapHttpTransport::QtSoapHttpTransport(QObject*)'
C:\Projects/sevSOAP.cpp:8: undefined reference to `QtSoapHttpTransport::setHost(QString const&, bool, int)'
C:\Projects/sevSOAP.cpp:12: undefined reference to `QtSoapHttpTransport::~QtSoapHttpTransport()'
```

What have i been doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have tried to make QtSOAP run under QtCreator:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "sevSOAP.h"

sevSOAP::sevSOAP(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent), http(this)
{
    connect(&http, SIGNAL(responseReady()), this, SLOT(getResponse()));

    QtSoapMessage request;

    request.setMethod("TCKimlikNoDogrula");

    request.addMethodArgument("TCKimlikNo", "", "10000000146");
    request.addMethodArgument("Ad", "", "mustafa");
    request.addMethodArgument("Soyad", "", "atatürk");
    request.addMethodArgument("DogumYili", "", "1881");

    http.setHost("tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr", true);
    http.setAction("http://tckimlik.nvi.gov.tr/WS/TCKimlikNoDogrula");
    http.submitRequest(request, "/Service/KPSPublic.asmx?op=TCKimlikNoDogrula");

    qDebug("Looking up population of...");
}

void sevSOAP::getResponse()
{
    // Get a reference to the response message.
    const QtSoapMessage &message = http.getResponse();

    // Check if the response is a SOAP Fault message
    if (message.isFault()) {
        qDebug("Error: %s", message.faultString().value().toString().toLatin1().constData());
    }
    else {
        // Get the return value, and print the result.
        const QtSoapType &response = message.returnValue();
        qDebug("%s has a population of %s (last updated at %s)",
               response["Country"].value().toString().toLatin1().constData(),
               response["Pop"].value().toString().toLatin1().constData(),
               response["Date"].value().toString().toLatin1().constData());
    }
}
```

this is the header file:

```
#ifndef SEVSOAP_H
#define SEVSOAP_H

#include <qtsoap.h>

class sevSOAP : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        sevSOAP(QObject *parent = 0);

    private slots:
        void getResponse();

    private:
        QtSoapHttpTransport http;
};

#endif
```

and i am getting this error output:

```
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/<user>/Projects/Release'
g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o release/TCKimlikNoSorgulama.exe release/qtsoap.o release/main.o release/newForm.o release/sevSOAP.o release/moc_qtsoap.o release/moc_newForm.o release/moc_sevSOAP.o  -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lmingw32 -lqtmain -LC:\Developement\Qt\5.2.0\mingw48_32\lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Network -lQt5Xml -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core 
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x458): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV10QtSoapType'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x6b8): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV16QtSoapSimpleType'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x718): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV11QtSoapArray'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x10aa): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV10QtSoapType'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x162a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV10QtSoapType'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x1732): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV10QtSoapType'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x2e5a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV11QtSoapArray'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x2f4b): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV11QtSoapArray'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x3656): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV12QtSoapStruct'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x36eb): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV12QtSoapStruct'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x384c): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV16QtSoapSimpleType'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x388b): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV16QtSoapSimpleType'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x38dc): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV16QtSoapSimpleType'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x3940): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV16QtSoapSimpleType'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x399c): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV16QtSoapSimpleType'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x39f7): more undefined references to `_imp___ZTV16QtSoapSimpleType' follow
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x43e8): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV12QtSoapStruct'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x4694): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV11QtSoapArray'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x6d34): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV12QtSoapStruct'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x7137): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV12QtSoapStruct'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x736f): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV12QtSoapStruct'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x7c5f): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV12QtSoapStruct'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x7e7b): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV12QtSoapStruct'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0x8394): more undefined references to `_imp___ZTV12QtSoapStruct' follow
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0xa38a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV21QtSoapTypeConstructorI12QtSoapStructE'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0xa3cd): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV21QtSoapTypeConstructorI11QtSoapArrayE'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0xa408): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV21QtSoapTypeConstructorI16QtSoapSimpleTypeE'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0xc430): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN19QtSoapHttpTransport13responseReadyEv'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0xc43b): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN19QtSoapHttpTransport13responseReadyERK13QtSoapMessage'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0xe4aa): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV12QtSoapStruct'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0xe7aa): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV19QtSoapHttpTransport'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text+0xe888): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV19QtSoapHttpTransport'
release/qtsoap.o:qtsoap.cpp:(.text$_ZN25QtSoapTypeConstructorBaseD1Ev[__ZN25QtSoapTypeConstructorBaseD1Ev]+0xffff1681): undefined reference to `_imp___ZTV25QtSoapTypeConstructorBase'
Makefile.Release:88: recipe for target 'release/TCKimlikNoSorgulama.exe' failed
c:/developement/qt/tools/mingw48_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: release/qtsoap.o: bad reloc address 0x1 in section `.text$_ZN25QtSoapTypeConstructorBaseD1Ev[__ZN25QtSoapTypeConstructorBaseD1Ev]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: The relevant code would be your .pro file. You need to link against the QtSoap library. (The QtSoap library might contain information on this)

Comment: I am using Netbeans for developement. There are no pro files. How could it be done in this case?

Comment: @salim_aliya: what buildsystem are you using? Have you made sure the the -lSoap or something like that is passed to your compiler?

Comment: i Am using the latest Qt library with Netbeans IDE. I have tried all day to implement QtSOAP to my application. By the way i tried it also directly in QtCreator, it's also putting out errors. See EDIT for this.

Comment: You have not answered the question. What buildsystem are you using in your project whenusing Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `qmake` based build system in your Qt software, you need to do the following:

```
include(C:/path/to/qtsoap.pri)
```

in your project file. This is necessary if you take a look at the examples. All of them are doing this. They are manipulating with it as a fake library as there is no actual library generated after the `./config && qmake-qt4 -r && make VERBOSE=1` process.

If you are using a different buildsystem, you will need to replicate the logic inside, but it is quite tricky for a newcomer, mostly because it is using some magic inside like phony target, undocumented rarity like `TEMPLATE += fakelib`, et al.

Just to avoid the confusion: this module has not yet been ported over to Qt 5, hence you cannot get it working off-hand without some work included. You need to stick to Qt 4 with it for the time being.

Comment: The include to the project file was already done. Still it's puttung out the same errors. When i am loading the "population" example project to QtCreator, it can't compile, 'cause it's claiming that QString has no member named "toAscii" in qtsoap.cpp line 3154. Maybe QtSOAP is just outdated, 'cause i'm using Qt Creator 5.2.0 und MinGW 4.8, which was installed by QtCreator.

Comment: @salim_aliya: toAscii() was removed in Qt 5. QtSoap does *not* work with Qt 5. This module has not really yet been ported over to Qt 5. It will only work with Qt 4!

Comment: @salim_aliya: edited the answer respectively. Anything left to be resolved here?

Comment: No, it's clear now: QtSOAP is just not supported bei Qt 5, so there are no questions anymore left. Thank you!! :-)